# Добавление данных после отправки формы form_alter

Tags: drupal

В свой модуль добавил код типа этого.

```
function ad_status_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
$form['actions']['copy'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#return_value' => 1,
  '#default_value' => 1,
  '#title' => t('Allow comments'),
);
```

Мне нужно чтобы при добавлении материала его параметры были именены. В моём случает это чекбокс, который разрешает или не разрешает комментарии. Как это сделать лучше?

Answer (score 1):

Это уже присутсвует с ядра, поэтому не нужно что то писать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нужно делать это из кода например в зависимости от значения чекбокса.

Тогна нужно использовать хук hook_form_alter

```
function MODULE_NAME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id){
  if ($form_id == 'review_node_form') {)
    $form['comment_access'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#return_value' => 1,
      '#default_value' => 1,
      '#title' => t('Allow comments'),
    );
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'MODULE_NAME_comment_access_form_submit_callback';
  }
}

function MODULE_NAME_comment_access_form_submit_callback(){
  $node = node_form_submit_build_node($form, $form_state);
  $node->comment = 1;
  node_save($node);
}
```

Comment: Если бы мне нужно было бы сделать это из ядра через панель управления администратора, то я бы не спрашивал. Я же спрашиваю хук, который перехватывает данные form_state и модифицирует их.

Comment: дополнил ответ, описал как сделать это из кода

Comment: Благодарю, решил таким образом.